# Push data in array inside document ready using angular 7 and jquery

Tags: angular, angular7

I would like push data in array of angular2+ using jquery but I have this error in console

> Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

The push() work outside $document.ready(function({
I would like to use it inside my component

```js
import { Component, OnInit, HostListener } from '@angular/core';
import { ProductsService } from '../services/products.service';
import { PinchZoomComponent, PinchZoomModule } from 'ngx-pinch-zoom';
import { Positions } from "../positions.model";
import { TemplateBindingParseResult } from '@angular/compiler';

declare var $:any

@Component({
  selector: 'app-mytickets',
  templateUrl: './mytickets.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./mytickets.component.css']
})

export class MyticketsComponent implements OnInit {

  tabs = []
  constructor(public productService: ProductsService) { }

  public ngOnInit() {

      $(document).ready(function() {

        $('.imgref').click(function(e) {
          this.tabs.push({"left": 200, "top":200}) // don't work
        });
        
      }
      
      this.tabs.push({"left": 200, "top":200}) // work
  }
  
  this.tabs.push({"left": 200, "top":200}) // work
  
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to use jQuery here?

Comment: I have an and I use offset() to get positions of multiple cursors, I would like to pass an array inside the main component. outside the doc.ready, is it possible ?

Comment: I don't believe you really need jQuery. In any case, srjkaa's answer is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
import { Component, OnInit, HostListener } from '@angular/core';
import { ProductsService } from '../services/products.service';
import { PinchZoomComponent, PinchZoomModule } from 'ngx-pinch-zoom';
import { Positions } from "../positions.model";
import { TemplateBindingParseResult } from '@angular/compiler';

declare var $:any

@Component({
  selector: 'app-mytickets',
  templateUrl: './mytickets.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./mytickets.component.css']
})

export class MyticketsComponent implements OnInit {

  tabs = []
  constructor(public productService: ProductsService) { }

  public ngOnInit() {

      $(document).ready(() => {

        $('.imgref').click((e) => {
          this.tabs.push({"left": 200, "top":200}) // don't work
        });
        
      }
      
      this.tabs.push({"left": 200, "top":200}) // work
  }
  
  this.tabs.push({"left": 200, "top":200}) // work
  
}
```

I can't reproduce it on stackblitz, but you can try this.
I guess the problem is in lost 'context' inside your functions.

Comment: not working, I have a new jquery error: r.getclientrects is not a function, Can I pass data from jquery to the component?

Comment: @kevinrichard

It's fix your problem described in a main post:
**Cannot read property 'push' of undefined**.

In code listed above I don't see nothing about 'r.getclientrects', so i can't help you with this part of code.

Comment: Okay, I finally found a solution. I declared a variable above @component
and now it works
I use the variable inside jquery and I use it again with Angular Var ( mindfuck )

Comment: @kevinrichard Congratulations! Good luck!